# How to loop arraylist string with increment in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am stuck with my loop where I want to loop the arraylist of string that contain data like this

```
[A,B,C,D,E,F]
```

where I want to loop the arraylist at the top row only like the image down below. The result that I get when I run the code here is the the same as the first image.

```
    Row roww1 = sheet.createRow(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < shiftname.size(); i++) {
            Cell toprow = roww1.createCell(i + 4);
            toprow.setCellValue(shiftname.get(i));
    }
```

[image]

This is the outcome that I want it to be

[image]

Comment: This is very basic. If `i` is {0,1,2,3,...} but you wants {0,3,6,9,...} then this is `i*3`. And if there shall be an offset of 4, to be the result {4,7,10,13,...} then this is `i*3+4`. So `createCell(i * 3 + 4)`.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks. it works. I am still a noob with looping. I guess I have to improve after this.